# Plotting and respresenting data points that are very similar in value

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have the following association,

```
l=<|"a" -> {0., 2., 6.75489, 61.7904, 320.131, 657.8, 1164.06, 1940., 
   3007.25, 3261.88, 4392.99, 14413.4, 21289.1, 57808.5, 106159., 
   139368., 139379., 342602., 615895., 1.43145*10^6, 2.20621*10^6, 
   2.47879*10^6, 2.68747*10^6, 2.76375*10^6, 3.53664*10^6, 
   3.64451*10^6}, 
 "b" -> {0., 2., 6.75489, 61.7904, 320.131, 657.8, 1164.06, 1940., 
   3007.25, 3261.88, 4392.99, 14413.4, 21289.1, 57808.5, 106159., 
   139368., 139379., 342602., 615895., 1.43145*10^6, 2.20621*10^6, 
   2.45453*10^6, 2.66188*10^6, 2.73768*10^6, 3.50395*10^6, 
   3.61124*10^6}, 
 "c" -> {0., 0., 2., 41.2611, 256.821, 577.537, 1030.19, 1755.01, 
   2773.22, 3013.34, 4029.42, 13314.7, 19798.1, 54972.5, 102016., 
   134697., 134709., 331601., 599840., 1.40305*10^6, 2.1656*10^6, 
   2.4356*10^6, 2.64172*10^6, 2.71694*10^6, 3.47819*10^6, 
   3.58453*10^6}, 
 "d" -> {0., 2., 4., 52.9126, 283.385, 566.745, 1041.59, 1726.21, 
   2725.01, 2974.69, 3978.01, 13432.5, 19863.2, 54476.7, 100631., 
   132115., 132127., 326176., 590263., 1.37284*10^6, 2.126*10^6, 
   2.3917*10^6, 2.59704*10^6, 2.67139*10^6, 3.41954*10^6, 
   3.52462*10^6}, 
 "e" -> {0., 2., 4.75489, 56.1808, 310.593, 646.928, 1142.95, 1889.13,
    2941.18, 3195.18, 4233.54, 14012.2, 20732.4, 56703.7, 104141., 
   137077., 137088., 337454., 608520., 1.41912*10^6, 2.187*10^6, 
   2.45935*10^6, 2.66729*10^6, 2.74308*10^6, 3.51111*10^6, 
   3.6187*10^6}, 
 "f" -> {0., 2., 6.75489, 61.7904, 320.131, 657.8, 1164.06, 1940., 
   3007.25, 3261.88, 4249.26, 14067.8, 20906.7, 57121.6, 104871., 
   137952., 137964., 339968., 612215., 1.42624*10^6, 2.1991*10^6, 
   2.47237*10^6, 2.68025*10^6, 2.75647*10^6, 3.52845*10^6, 
   3.63619*10^6}, 
 "g" -> {0., 2., 6.75489, 61.7904, 320.131, 657.8, 1164.06, 1940., 
   3007.25, 3261.88, 4190.77, 13920.9, 20729.5, 56781.1, 104218., 
   136967., 136979., 337940., 609048., 1.42076*10^6, 2.1924*10^6, 
   2.46547*10^6, 2.67247*10^6, 2.74869*10^6, 3.51935*10^6, 
   3.62716*10^6}, 
 "h" -> {0., 2., 6.75489, 61.7904, 320.131, 657.8, 1164.06, 1940., 
   3007.25, 3261.88, 4392.99, 14413.4, 21289.1, 57808.5, 106159., 
   139368., 139379., 342602., 589439., 1.3696*10^6, 2.11854*10^6, 
   2.38389*10^6, 2.58508*10^6, 2.65975*10^6, 3.40909*10^6, 
   3.5144*10^6}, 
 "i" -> {0., 2., 6.75489, 61.7904, 320.131, 657.8, 1164.06, 1940., 
   3007.25, 3261.88, 4392.99, 14413.4, 21289.1, 57808.5, 106159., 
   139368., 139379., 342602., 615895., 1.43145*10^6, 2.15035*10^6, 
   2.41794*10^6, 2.62462*10^6, 2.6994*10^6, 3.45658*10^6, 
   3.56208*10^6}, 
 "j" -> {0., 2., 6.75489, 61.7904, 320.131, 657.8, 1164.06, 1940., 
   3007.25, 3261.88, 4392.99, 14413.4, 21289.1, 57808.5, 106159., 
   139368., 139379., 342602., 607965., 1.41746*10^6, 2.18142*10^6, 
   2.45305*10^6, 2.66013*10^6, 2.73584*10^6, 3.50222*10^6, 
   3.60968*10^6}, 
 "k" -> {0., 2., 6.75489, 61.7904, 320.131, 657.8, 1164.06, 1940., 
   3007.25, 3261.88, 4392.99, 14413.4, 21289.1, 57808.5, 106159., 
   139368., 139379., 342602., 615895., 1.43145*10^6, 2.18195*10^6, 
   2.45385*10^6, 2.66176*10^6, 2.73761*10^6, 3.50453*10^6, 
   3.61183*10^6}|>;
```

As you can see the numbers in each column are very close to each other. I am trying to make a nice representation of this, I plot them as follow:

```
ListLogPlot[Evaluate[l // Values], Joined -> True, 
 PlotLabels -> Placed[l // Keys, Right]]
```

which gives:
[image]
as you can see however, since the points are very close to each other their line profile is almost indistinguishable, also because of that the labels are now interfering with one another. I wonder what's the best way when one deals which such situations? How does one would go about representing such data?

Comment: You can plot differences between each `Key` and e.g. first one, and show two plots: `ListLinePlot[Thread[Callout[l[[1]] - # & /@ (l // Values), l // Keys]], 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLabel -> "Differences"]` and `ListLogPlot[l[[1]] - # & /@ (l // Values), PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLabel -> "Differences", Joined -> True]` because behaviour is very different in different abscissa ranges.

Comment: Thank you for this :)

Comment: You can also combine those using `Inset`: `ListLinePlot[Thread[Callout[l[[1]] - # & /@ (l // Values), l // Keys]], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLabel -> "Differences", Epilog -> Inset[ListLogPlot[l[[1]] - # & /@ (l // Values), 
    PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 20}, All}, Frame -> True, Joined -> True], Scaled[{0.05, 0.9}], {Left, Top}, Scaled[0.6]]]`.